# getting following error when i start websphere v8.5 liberty profile

Tags: java, spring, websphere, profile, websphere-liberty

i am getting the error while starting the application. kindly look at log and help me out

```
00000013 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction     I CWWKZ0018I: Starting application program-integration-portal.
[2/7/14 13:02:45:201 IST] 00000013 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.ibm.ws.javaee.ddmodel.common.ResourceRefType.ResAuthEnum.CONTAINER com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction 135" at ffdc_14.02.07_13.02.45.0.log
[2/7/14 13:02:45:209 IST] 00000013 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.ibm.ws.javaee.ddmodel.common.ResourceRefType.ResAuthEnum.CONTAINER com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction$1 applicationStartFail" at ffdc_14.02.07_13.02.45.1.log
[2/7/14 13:02:45:210 IST] 00000013 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction     E CWWKZ0002E: An exception occurred while starting the application program-integration-portal. The exception message was: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.ibm.ws.javaee.ddmodel.common.ResourceRefType.ResAuthEnum.CONTAINER
[2/7/14 13:02:45:248 IST] 00000017 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0008I: Feature update completed in 3.307 seconds.
[2/7/14 13:02:45:248 IST] 00000017 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0011I: The server websphere is ready to run a smarter planet.
```

Answer (score 2):

This error means you specified `<res-auth>CONTAINER</res-auth>` rather than `<res-auth>Container</res-auth>` in your web.xml and your web.xml version is 2.3 or higher.